# kohana 3 routing problem with controller action parameter

Tags: routes, kohana-3

I have this routing defined in my module's init.php;

```
Route::set('store', 'store/<store_id>(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))', 
  array(
    'store_id' => '\d+'
  ))
  ->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'main',
    'action'     => 'index',
  ));
```

and the default route in bootstrap.php is still intact.

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'welcome',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

my Controller_Item class;

```
class Controller_Item extends Controller {
    function action_category($category_id)
    {
        echo 'Category ID: '.$category_id;
    }
}
```

Using `http://mydomain.com/item/category/8`
Output:

```
Category ID: 8
```

they point to correct routing which was;
**Controller_Item** and method **action_category(8)**

The problem is when using modified route;
`http://mydomain.com/store/1/item/category/8`
Output:

```
Category ID: 1
```

it become **action_category(1)** (it takes the parameter from <store_id>)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get param by name:

```
$id = $this->request->param('id');
```